# GAMS: retrieve information from solution

Tags: find, set, equation-solving, gams-math

GAMS: I think I have a pretty simple question, however I'm stuck and was wondering if someone could help here.

A simplified version of my model looks like this:

```
    set(i,t) ;
    parameter price
              D;
    variable p(i,t) 
             e(i,t);
     equations 
             Equation1 
obj.. C=sum((i,t), p(i,t)*price);
 Model file /all/ ;
 Solve file minimizing C using MIP ;
 Display C.l;
```

p(i,t) and e(i,t) are related:

```
 Equation1 .. e(i,t)=e=e(i,t-1)+p(i,t)*D
```

Now I want to retrieve information from the solution: lets say I want to know at what t e(i,t) has a certain value for example --> e(i,t)= x(i) or otherwise formulated e(i,t=TD)=x(i) find TD, where x(i) thus is depending on i. Does anyone know how I can write this in to my GAMs model? To be clear I do not want to change anything about my solution and the model I have runs; I just want to retrieve this information from the solution given.

So far I tried a couple of thing and nothing worked. I think that this must be simple, can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
set i /i1*i10/
    t /t1*t10/;
variable e(i,t);

*some random dummy "solution"
e.l(i,t) = uniformInt(1,10);

set find5(i,t) 'find all combinations of i and t for which e.l=5';

find5(i,t)$(e.l(i,t)=5) = yes;

display e.l,find5;
```

Hope that helps,
Lutz

Comment: Thanks you for the quick response and this worked! I already tried a couple of times to achieve this with ordered sets, but your response finally showed a correct way of doing it!

Comment: Just one last question: in the GDX file the number of t appear right next to the answer. However when display it or unload it I end up with the whole graph with yes and empty cells. Is there a way to only exporting the value of T instead of the whole graph?

Comment: T is a set in my example so it actually has no value. So I am not exactly sure what you mean by "in the GDX file the number of t appear right next to the answer". But if you have just one element in a set and want to get a number out of this, you might want to check the ord operator like here:

  set tt    / t1*t10 /
      t(tt) / t5     /;
  scalar selectedT;
  
  selectedT = sum(t(tt), ord(tt));
  display selectedT;

Comment: Yes indeed I want a scalar as output! However in reality my x is depending on i (so as asked in the original question: e(i,t=TD)=x(i) find TD or as it is in your response 'find5(i,t)$(e.l(i,t)=Ed(i)) = yes'. If I enter t(tt) /tEd(i)/ I receive an error (Domain list redefined). I will update the the original question and was wondering if you how I could enter this into my program?

Comment: So, you want to see one number for each i, right? Just add this to the end of my original example and it should work: parameter selectedT(i);
selectedT(i) = sum(t$find5(i,t), ord(t));
display selectedT;